# Use Case Inlcude vs Extend

Tags: uml, use-case, use-case-diagram

I would like to show Use Case diagram for the following behaviour:
When a user goes to Home page, the system shows a List of vacations. user can scroll through the list which is filtered and sorted by default parameters. User can enter parameters for filtering the list and click "Search". User can View details of a vacation by clicking "View details".

Here is a wireframe: [image]

I did the Use Case diagram here:
[image]

Is it correct to depict UC "View vacation details" as extended case from basic case "Search vacations"?

Or is it more correct to make a basic case "View vacation details" and from this case make include case "Search vacations" as shown here: [image]

Also, there is one more use case "Edit vacation details". This could be performed if a user clicked "View details" and then the system shows a new page with vacation details and on this page a user can click on "Edit vacation details". That is why I made a base use case "Edit vacation details" whihc includes "View vacation details", I hope this is correct as well.

Comment: Neither of your bubbles shows a use case. They are all plain functions. I recommend reading Bittner/Spence about use case modeling.

Comment: @qwerty_so so what would you suggest how should the use case diagram look like for my problem?

Comment: Look for what is bringing added value to the actor. Functions are a means of reaching the goal and go as actions into activities. UC is not functional decomposition but the pure opposite: synthesis of functions to show a single goal.